# Querying a pivot table through a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm Using Laravel 5.1 and have these four database tables

`posts` containing posts from Facebook. The `posts` table has a foreign key `page_id`. It's a refernece to the

`pages` table, which contains all facebook pages.

`category` table contains data for the categories in my project, e.g. `funny`, `videos`, etc.

`category_page` is a pivot table which saves the `category_id` and the `page_id`

---

What I now want to do, is to get all posts, that have been posted by a page in a specific category.

So, let's assume I have three pages

1: Mesut Oezil
2: Borussia Dortmund
3: BMW

The first two pages are in the category `sports` and the last one in `cars`. Now I want to get every post that has been posted by the pages from the category `sport`.

I have already defined the relation ships

Class Page:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Class Category:

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class);
}
```

Now, I'm getting my posts

```
$topPosts = (new Post)->where('fb_created_time', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString())
    ->visible()
    ->orderBy('total_count', 'desc');
```

And now I want to additional filter only the posts from the pages in a specific category. I managed to get pages from a specific category with this code here

```
$pages = Page::with('categories')
    ->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
        return $query->where('category_id', 1);
    })->get();
```

But how would I chain this into the posts? Or is it even good to use `whereHas`? What's the best practice here?

Comment: Try `Pages::with('posts') -> with('categories')....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you want to get posts, what belongs to a specific category, through pages.

In this case your setup is fine, you can make queries through relationships:

```
$category_id = 2;
Post::whereHas('page.categories', function($q) use($category_id) {
    $q->where('categories.id', $category_id);
})->get();
```

In your Post class:

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}
```

It will make one nested query.

Comment: Thanks. Already had the relation in my Postclass. I'm already pretty fluent in Eloquent, but when it comes to multiple talbes I'm kinda stuck!